# Repeating a repeated sequence

Tags: r, sequence, replicate

We want to get an array that looks like this:

```
1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4
```

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: it thought about a for loop, but isnt there a simpler way?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do it with a single `rep` call. The `each` and `times` parameters are evaluated sequentially with the `each` being done first.

```
rep(1:4, times=3, each=3)  # 'each' done first regardless of order of named parameters
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 20):

Or, simpler (assuming you mean a vector, not an array)

```
rep(rep(1:4,each=3),3)
```

Comment: Looking at this years later, I'm not sure that it is simpler, but I think a case could be made that it is more flexible in that you could use it to perform the "times" operation first to be followed by "each" processing.

Answer (score 9):

42-'s answer will work if your sequence of numbers incrementally increases by 1. However, if you want to include a sequence of numbers that increase by a set interval (e.g. from 0 to 60 by 15) you can do this:

```
rep(seq(0,60,15), times = 3)
[1]  0 15 30 45 60  0 15 30 45 60  0 15 30 45 60
```

You just have to change the number of times you want this to repeat.

Comment: To further randomise the resulting vector (or change the order of the vector randomly), just do: sample(rep(seq(0,60,15), times = 3))

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
rep(sapply(1:4, function(x) {rep(x, 3)}), 3)
```

rep(x, N) returns a vector repeating x N times. sapply applies the given function to each element of the vector 1:4 separately, repeating each element 3 times consecutively.

Comment: You should take a look at Dieter's answer - the 'each' parameter would do what you're doing a lot nicer than using a call to sapply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using array manipulation with `aperm`. The idea is to construct an array containing the values. Rearrange them so they match the desired output using `aperm`, and then "unfold" the array with `c`.

```
c(aperm(array(1:4, dim=c(4,3,3)), c(2, 1, 3)))
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4
```