# Creating a repeating sequence in R

Tags: r, seq, rep

I need to create a pattern like this with the `rep()` and `seq()` commands.
It should look like this:

`[1] 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.8 0.8 0.8 1.6 1.6 1.6 2.4 2.4 2.4 3.2 3.2 3.2 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.8
[20] 4.8 4.8`

Do you have any idea how to do so?

Comment: This is already answered here: [Repeating a repeated sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180125/repeating-a-repeated-sequence)

Comment: @Miha The link you provided does not include `seq`

Comment: @P Lapointe the point of my comment was that with the little effort he could found the answer to his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
rep(seq(0,4.8,by=0.8),each=3)
[1] 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.8 0.8 0.8 1.6 1.6 1.6 2.4 2.4 2.4 3.2 3.2 3.2 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.8 4.8 4.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mySeq <- c()
for (i in seq(0, 4.8, by = 0.8)) {
    mySeq <- c(mySeq, rep(i, 3))
}

mySeq
[1] 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.8 0.8 0.8 1.6 1.6 1.6 2.4 2.4 2.4 3.2 3.2 3.2 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.8 4.8 4.8
```